# How to use SwapChainPanel in XAML Islands

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-community-toolkit

I have followed the instructions here to create a sample app that uses XAML Islands to add controls like `InkCanvas` and `CalendarView`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/host-standard-control-with-xaml-islands

However, despite the Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.Controls package advertising that it provides `SwapChainPanel`, the control does not appear in the list of controls available in the namespace.  I did some digging and realized that it's because `SwapChainPanel` is marked as `internal`: https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32/blob/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.Controls/SwapChainPanel/SwapChainPanel.cs#L17
and therefore is not publicly visible which means it can't be used according to the tutorial for XAML Islands.

So, it's not very clear how to create an app which uses a `SwapChainPanel` control with XAML Islands.  Is there a sample somewhere?

In addition to this, I am very interested to know if there is any way to use a `SwapChainPanel` in an app that targets .NET Framework instead of .NET Core.  While the [official MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/xaml-islands) for XAML Islands mentions that .NET Core **must** be used, the [first official Windows Developer blog post on XAML Islands](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2019/06/13/xaml-islands-v1-updates-and-roadmap/) says otherwise and implies that all of the controls included in Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.Controls would be compatible with .NET Framework, per this paragraph:

> The .NET wrapped controls are supported in .NET Framework and .NET Core 3. The .NET host control (WindowsXamlHost) is available for Windows Forms and WPF. This control allows you to host UWP XAML content. If the UWP XAML content is a control that ships with the Windows 10 platform such as ColorPicker or NavigationView, you can target the .NET Framework 4.7.2 or NET Core 3.

So which is correct?

Comment: Take another look at that code you linked. /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="SwapChainPanel"/> class, a
        /// Wpf-enabled wrapper for <see cref="windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.SwapChainPanel"/>
        /// </summary>
        public SwapChainPanel()
            : this(typeof(windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.SwapChainPanel).FullName)
        {

Comment: @Andy Yes, I saw that.  Trying to use it yields `error CS0122: 'SwapChainPanel' is inaccessible due to its protection level`.  Again, because it is internal.  Unless there is a different way that it is supposed to be done.  Hence, why I am asking for an example.

Answer (score 0):

There is an example of how to use a `SwapChainPanel` in WPF available in Microsoft's official [GitHub respository](https://github.com/microsoft/Xaml-Islands-Samples/tree/c0f357a2b16591001b7796d73f80651f2813cb1a/Standalone_Samples/WinForms_WPF_Core3).

It's apparently fairly complicated. Please refer to [this](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32/issues/227) GitHub issue for more information.